# Bind Middle Click To Keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, key-binding

does anyone know a way to bind the middle click function of a mouse to a key in ubuntu? Something like this answer here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/7769/keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-the-primary-selection
but for the click function of the scroll wheel. All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Middle mouse click is pretty much reserved and cannot be changed without a 3rd party application.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/mouse-middleclick.html.en

Perhaps XMouse Button Control may be of use?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this on Wayland using [input-mapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper).